How to repair a wide expansion joint between garage and driveway?


This expansion joint between my garage and driveway is about 3.5 inches wide. Most of the solutions I found online, including backer rods and self leveling caulk, are for gaps narrower than 1 inch. My question is, would they work for my situation? Or is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

a: cut a 1/2" recess on both sides and fit a 4-1/2" wide drain grille.
b: 3" pavers.

Depends how much depth you have to work with.  You could clean it up—get all the old sealant out—and fill it with mortar or a lightweight concrete.  Maybe run a #3 rebar down the center.  Then use an elastomeric sealant to seal the joints between the concrete and mortar.  That section under the siding may be a problem.
